# Understanding 2d arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

All i am trying with the following source code, is to understand in depth how 2d arrays (tables) works in C. The code bellow may seems much but as you can see its nothing but simple prints and assignments.

Code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

char** as = (char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    as[i] = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
} 

strcpy(&as[0][0],"a");
strcpy(&as[0][1],"b");
strcpy(&as[0][2],"c");
strcpy(&as[1][0],"aa");
strcpy(&as[1][1],"bb");
strcpy(&as[1][2],"cc");

printf("as[0][0] <%s>\n",&as[0][0]);
printf("as[0][1] <%s>\n",&as[0][1]);
printf("as[0][2] <%s>\n",&as[0][2]);
printf("as[1][0] <%s>\n",&as[1][0]);
printf("as[1][1] <%s>\n",&as[1][1]);
printf("as[1][2] <%s>\n",&as[1][2]);

for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    free(as[i]);
}
free(as);

/*************** PART 2 **********************/
as = (char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    as[i] = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
} 

printf("enter:as[0][0]: "); scanf("%s",&as[0][0]); // Input: a
printf("enter:as[0][1]: "); scanf("%s",&as[0][1]); // Input: b
printf("enter:as[0][2]: "); scanf("%s",&as[0][2]); // Input: c
printf("enter:as[1][0]: "); scanf("%s",&as[1][0]); // Input: aa
printf("enter:as[1][1]: "); scanf("%s",&as[1][1]); // Input: bb
printf("enter:as[1][2]: "); scanf("%s",&as[1][2]); // Input: cc

printf("as[0][0] <%s>\n",&as[0][0]);
printf("as[0][1] <%s>\n",&as[0][1]);
printf("as[0][2] <%s>\n",&as[0][2]);
printf("as[1][0] <%s>\n",&as[1][0]);
printf("as[1][1] <%s>\n",&as[1][1]);
printf("as[1][2] <%s>\n",&as[1][2]);

for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    free(as[i]);
}
free(as);

return 0;
}
```

The result i am excepting is something like the tab on the left but all i am getting into `./a.out` is the tab on the right

```
as[0][0] <a>  }                           as[0][0] <abc>  }
as[0][1] <b>  }                           as[0][1] <bc>   }
as[0][2] <c>  }                           as[0][2] <c>    }
as[1][0] <aa> }  Excepted Result          as[1][0] <abcc> }  Final Result
as[1][1] <bb> }                           as[1][1] <bcc>  }
as[1][2] <cc> }                           as[1][2] <cc>   }
```

My first thought is that i am not using correctly `strcpy()`. That's why /**PART2**/ exists in the code, but gives out the same results.

I know there is lot of same issue topics explaining 2d arrays and i did my fair research getting around the above subject.
A

Comment: `&as[0][0]` is equivalent to `as[0]`

Comment: @user1937198 How then i print each column of row zero?

Comment: Use an array of strings, not an array of chars.

Comment: Before tackling "2D arrays" you need to understand how simple C strings (1D character arrays) work. Also, `(char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));` and `(char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));` make no sense whatsoever. Where does `int` come from?

Comment: @n.m. thats a simple copy paste mistake

Comment: I suggest you put this code aside, and do the same `strcpy` and `scanf` exercise with a single `char mystring[100]`. No dynamic allocation and no 2D. In order to understand what's going on, peek into the progarm with a debugger and watch how `mystring` changes at each step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: you don't actually have  a 2D array.

```
char** as = (char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    as[i] = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
}
```

This allocates a 1D array, and points `as` to it. Then, for each element, it allocates space and assigns the pointer to that space to the element. So what you have is a 1D array where each element is a pointer to another 1D array; let's call this a "2 level array" although I'm not sure if there's a better term available.

For a 2D array, you would instead write:

```
char (*as)[2][3] = malloc(2 * 3 * sizeof(char));
```

However, if you want the array to hold strings (as `char *`) instead of individual characters then your declaration would need to be:

```
char *(*as)[2][3] = malloc(2 * 3 * sizeof(char));
```

Alternatively, your original code could be changed for a 2 level array of `char *`:

```
char*** as = malloc(2 * sizeof(char **));
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    as[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
}
```

In both cases, you also need to allocate storage for the strings themselves. Instead of:

```
strcpy(&as[0][0],"a");
```

you should probably use:

```
 as[0][0] = strdup("a");
```

So, what actually happened with your code to give you the results you got? well, here:

```
strcpy(&as[0][0],"a");
strcpy(&as[0][1],"b");
strcpy(&as[0][2],"c");
strcpy(&as[1][0],"aa");
strcpy(&as[1][1],"bb");
strcpy(&as[1][2],"cc");
```

If `as` is a `char **`, then `as[0]` is a `char *` and `as[0][0]` is a simple `char`. You are then taking the address of this and copying an entire string to it. At best, this is odd; at worst, particularly for that last line, it's undefined behaviour - because you are copying past the end of an allocated array.

That is:

```
strcpy(&as[1][2],"cc");
```

You are copying to the 3rd and "4th" character of `as[1]` (that is, positions 2 and 3). But you only allocated space for 3:

```
as[i] = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
```

(In fact, an additional two lines above have the same issue, because copying a string also copies the "nul terminator" byte at the end of the string).

When you print the strings, you print the result of the previous `strcpy` invocations. Consider, for `as[0]`:

```
strcpy(&as[0][0],"a");
```

Ok, `as[0]` now contains "a", represented as `'a'` in `as[0][0]` and `'\0'`, the string terminator, in `as[0][1]`.

```
strcpy(&as[0][1],"b");
```

Now, you have `'b'` in `as[0][1]` and `'\0'` in `as[0][2]`.

```
strcpy(&as[0][2],"c");
```

As explained before, this is invalid; but supposing we ignore that for now, you end up with:

`as[0][0]` = 'a'
   `as[0][1]` = 'b'
   `as[0][2]` = 'c'

However, now you are printing:

```
printf("as[0][0] <%s>\n",&as[0][0]);
```

... and you say that you expect "a" as the output. However, the string `as[0]` contains "abc", (and is nul terminated only due to an accident of behaviour) so that is what you get when you print it.

To clarify:

- `as[0]` and `as[1]` are string pointers
- `as[0][i]`, for any `i`, is a character within the string pointed to by `as[0]`

When you take the address of a character within a string, and copy another string to that address, you copy over the containing string starting at that particular character.

Comment: That helps me understand a lot i had misunderstood! But how then you are assigning strings into "table cells" in that case?

Comment: @MrDiaman I've edited a little to clarify, but I'm not sure I understand your question. A string is not a table cell. There is not really a "table" in your example. You haven't got a 2d array.

Comment: Lets say we have a table like sort of storage with rows and columns (i thought that what char** is)
Is there a way for me to store strings into this "table cells" without using structs?

Comment: @printfmyname no, with that declaration `as` would be a pointer to a 2D array of `char`.

Comment: @MrDiaman a 2D array is like a table, and you can also use the 2-level array that you actually have to hold contents of such a table, but the way to store an element in a cell is simply: `as[0][0] = 'a';` - note that this stores a character, not a string, because with the declaration you used the elements are `char`. If you want each element to be a string, you need an extra `*`. I'll add a little more to the answer.